# Keep getting {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"}, unknown error in html or php?

Tags: php

The only functioning form I want is on the main index page, since that is the core of the web application, I have everything laid out with the following code with the help of Jquery mobile;

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>jQuery Mobile: Theme Download</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/TravelodgeTheme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1><img src="themes/images/TravelodgeHotelLogo.png" alt="" style="width:123.5px;height:26.25px;"></h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="spreadsheet.html" data-icon="grid">Spreadsheet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="information.html" data-icon="info">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <form action="store.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <select name="select-choice-a" id="select-choice-a" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option>Floor</option>
                        <option value="floor1">1</option>
                        <option value="floor2">2</option>
                        <option value="floor3">3</option>
                        <option value="floor4">4</option>
                        <option value="floor5">5</option>
                        <option value="floor6">6</option>
                        <option value="floor7">7</option>
                        <option value="floor8">8</option>
                        <option value="floor9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <select name="select-choice-b" id="select-choice-b" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option>Room</option>
                        <option value="room1">1</option>
                        <option value="room2">2</option>
                        <option value="room3">3</option>
                        <option value="room4">4</option>
                        <option value="room5">5</option>
                        <option value="room6">6</option>
                        <option value="room7">7</option>
                        <option value="room8">8</option>
                        <option value="room9">9</option><option value="room10">10</option>
                        <option value="room11">11</option>
                        <option value="room12">12</option>
                        <option value="room13">13</option>
                        <option value="room14">14</option>
                        <option value="room15">15</option>
                        <option value="room16">16</option>
                        <option value="room17">17</option>
                        <option value="room18">18</option><option value="room19">19</option><option value="room20">20</option><option value="room21">21</option><option value="room22">22</option><option value="room23">23</option><option value="room24">24</option><option value="room25">25</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <select name="select-choice-c" id="select-choice-c" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option>Item</option>
                        <option value="iron">Iron</option>
                        <option value="microwave">Microwave</option>
                        <option value="kettle">Kettle</option>
                        <option value="tv">TV</option>
                        <option value="clockradio">Clock Radio</option>
                        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <select name="select-choice-d" id="select-choice-d" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option>Brand</option>
                        <option value="kambrookki785">Iron – KAMBROOK KI785</option>
                        <option value="samsungblack">Microwave – SAMSUNG BLACK</option>
                        <option value="neroexpressblack">Kettle – NERO EXPRESS BLACK</option>
                        <option value="samsung43">TV – SAMSUNG 43”</option>
                        <option value="philips40">TV - PHILIPS 40”</option>
                        <option value="philips">Clock Radio – PHILIPS</option>              <option value="ihome">Clock Radio – IHOME</option><option value="blacktel">Phone – BLACK TEL</option>
                        <option value="other">OTHER</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <select name="select-choice-e" id="select-choice-e" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option>Quality</option>
                        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
                        <option value="verybad">Very Bad</option>
                        <option value="bad">Bad</option>
                        <option value="average">Average</option>
                        <option value="good">Good</option>
                        <option value="verygood">Very Good</option>             <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" data-theme="d">Cancel</button></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And in the form section the action calls for the store.php which uses this small simple code (which could be completely wrong) with the intention of storing the current selected variables from each selection to prepare for download and conversion to excel database;

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $select-choice-a=$_POST['select-choice-a'];
    $select-choice-b=$_POST['select-choice-b'];
    $select-choice-c=$_POST['select-choice-c'];
    $select-choice-d=$_POST['select-choice-d'];
    $select-choice-e=$_POST['select-choice-e'];
    //Storing selected Value in Variable
    }
    ?>
```

However when I run live preview in chrome I get the following error message {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"}, I read a lot of forums saying to check the method but im not sure what Im doing wrong. Any help or guidance to a forum with a similiar instance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hyphens for your variable names.

So try this?

```
$select_choice_a=$_POST['select-choice-a'];
$select_choice_b=$_POST['select-choice-b'];
$select_choice_c=$_POST['select-choice-c'];
$select_choice_d=$_POST['select-choice-d'];
$select_choice_e=$_POST['select-choice-e'];
```